# Euler's Formula - Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

How does one get from
$$\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{6}\left(\mathrm{e}^{−5\mathrm{i}\pi/6}+\mathrm{e}^{−5i\pi/2}+\mathrm{e}^{−\mathrm{i}\pi/6}\right)$$
to
$$-\frac{2π(\mathrm{i}^2)}{6}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)?$$

Thanks.

P.S. Please see link for further clarification

[Euler's idenity used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnRuM.png)

Comment: Please check if I have correctly edited your question.

Comment: Yes  many thanks Nicholas, thats exactly how it should be

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this:

$\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}, e^{i\theta} = cos(\theta) + i \cdot \sin(\theta)$

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{1}{2}$

enough?

$e^{-5\pi/6} = - \cos(\pi/6) - i \sin(\pi/6) $

$e^{-\pi/6} =  \cos(\pi/6) - i \sin(\pi/6) $

$e^{-5\pi/2} =  \cos(-\pi/2) + i \sin(-\pi/2) = - i \sin(\pi/2)$

Comment: Hi Vincent, yep that I know. However still unsure how they got from [exp(−5iπ/6) + exp(−5iπ/2) + exp(−iπ/6)] -> [2sin(1/6π) + sin(π/2)]

Comment: Still unsure about how they got 2 lot's of sine function; would that require 4 complex exponetial function?

Comment: Thanks Vincent, you're a life saver!

Comment: You welcome. Try a little harder before asking next time.

Comment: Hi Vincent, how does e−5π/6=−cos(π/6)−isin(π/6)? Why isnt the argument of the sine and cosine (5pi/6)?

Comment: Didn't you learn that $\cos(x+\pi) = - \cos(x) $ and $ \sin(x+\pi) = - \sin(x) $?